# Toggle event capturing in jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-events

I have elements on my page (***`id=itemid`***) that when hovered over cause another element (***`id=panel`***) to become visible (via fadeIn). Basically a hover event on `itemid` causes panel to `fadeIn` and `mouseOut` leads to `fadeOut`.

I want to make a button so that when clicked the panel element does not `fadeIn` or out but stays visible. When that button is clicked, the `mouseIn` and `mouseOut` events should work again.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.itemid').hover(
        function () {
            $('.panel').fadeIn(300);
        },
        function () {
            $('.panel').fadeOut(200);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Do the fade in/out on hover with a class, then simply add/remove said class on click.

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag for whether to do the fading or not:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var fadeEnabled = true;
$('.itemid').hover(
    function () {
        if (fadeEnabled) {
            $('.panel').fadeIn(300);
        }
    },
    function () {
        if (fadeEnabled) {
            $('.panel').fadeOut(200);
        }
    }
);

$("#myButton").click(function() {
     fadeEnabled = !fadeEnabled;
});

});
```

Then, just toggle that flag with your button and it will enable or disable the fade behavior.

Answer (score -1):

On click of the button, use $(selector).unbind('mousein') on your object/item to deregister the events., and the reregister on another click of the button. Keep toggling on each click of the button.